# EPPlus get excel row and columns count

Tags: c#, epplus

I have an excel file which has say 5 columns and 5 rows.

I am using EPPlus (.net core c#)to parse the contents of the file.

I have the below code to count the rows and columns and then parse contents of this excel file.

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
{    
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
    int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
    int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;

    for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
        {
            //Parse here
        }
    }
}
```

With 5 rows and 5 columns of data as mentioned this works fine.

If I update and save the same file, and delete say 3 rows and 3 columns.

Now if I read this file again it still shows 5 columns and rows. Not sure if there is another way to read actual rows and columns?

Am I missing something here.

Comment: This is not possible unless you are updating the wrong file or have the original stored somewhere on server disk or memory. Anyway the code you posted is not the problem, that should be how you trigger that code when and where.

Comment: Is there any other option I can look for. I mean how to handle such cases when user updates an existing excel file and uploads it.

Comment: If you always process the latest file there should not be an issue.

Comment: You should use something like FileSystemWatcher class to check if file is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
    {    
        string directoryServerPath = // your file saving path in server;

        if (!Directory.Exists(directoryServerPath))
          Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryServerPath);                     

        System.IO.DirectoryInfo directoryFiles = new DirectoryInfo(directoryServerPath);
        foreach (FileInfo file in directoryFiles.GetFiles())
        {
         file.IsReadOnly = false;
         file.Delete();
        }

        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
        int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
        int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;

        for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
            {
                //Parse here
            }
        }

       package.SaveAs(new System.IO.FileInfo(directoryServerPath + fileName));
                    System.IO.File.SetAttributes(directoryServerPath + fileName, FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
    }
```